# SQL IN Clause - get back IN elements that did not match

Tags: mysql, sql, in-clause

I'd like to run an SQL query to determine the occupants of a number of rooms. I'd also like to see which rooms are empty.

I can find the occupants using SQL of the form:

```
SELECT Room, OccupantName
FROM Rooms
WHERE Rooms IN ("Room 1", "Room 2", "Room 3", "Room 4")
```

However, if only Rooms 1 and 2 have occupants, eg

```
Room    OccupantName
Room 1, Person A
Room 2, Person B
```

how can I get something of the form:

```
Room    OccupantName
Room 1, Person A
Room 2, Person B
Room 3, Nobody
Room 4, Nobody
```

Is there a way to select out the elements of the IN clause that did not return results and show "Nobody"?

Comment: Try using a IFNULL condition, can you let us know what table stores the occupant name?

Comment: The question would be, what is actually in your tables when you query?

Comment: You have a poor table design here. The Rooms table should include all tables - no matter if they have occupants or not!

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your `Rooms` table only contains data for active occupancies.  This makes sense in many ways, because you don't want to store information about people which aren't really occupying a room.  But it poses a challenge to generate your desired result set, because the missing rooms aren't present in `Rooms`.

One option here is the "calendar table" approach.  You can `LEFT JOIN` a table containing all rooms to your current `Rooms` table, and then label missing occupants as `nobody`.

```
SELECT t1.Room,
       COALESCE(t2.OccupantName, 'Nobody') AS OccupantName
FROM
(
    SELECT "Room 1" AS Room
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Room 2"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Room 3"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Room 4"
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN Rooms AS t2
    ON t1.Room = t2.Rooms
```

Note that I used an line subquery to create a table for all rooms.  In practice, you could create an actual table in Workbench containing this information.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rooms without an occupant are set to NULL, you could use a case statement:

```
SELECT Room, CASE WHEN OccupantName IS NULL THEN 'Nobody' Else OccupantName END
FROM   Rooms
WHERE  Room IN ("Room 1", "Room 2", "Room 3", "Room 4")
```

Or just filter them out with a where clause:

```
SELECT Room, OccupantName
FROM   Rooms
WHERE  Room IN ("Room 1", "Room 2", "Room 3", "Room 4")
    AND OccupantName IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have two separate tables. one with list of rooms and second on the existing tables then you can select by LEFT join experession.

for example the RoomsList table will be like:

```
Room

Room 1

Room 2

Room 3

Room 4

Room 5

Room 6

Room 7
```

and then the query will be like:

```
SELECT Room, OccupantName

FROM RoomsList Left Join Rooms

ON RoomsList.Room=Rooms.Room

WHERE RoomsList.Room IN ("Room 1", "Room 2", "Room 3", "Room 4")
```

Comment: I don't follow this because in the question they want the output to show "Nobody" where there is no occupant. This answer doesn't include "nobody".

Answer (score 0):

Just a single `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` will help you to get the desired output. You are almost near to your solution and there are many ways as you can see in the given answers but I suggest you to do slight change your code as below:

```
SELECT Room, COALESCE(OccupantName, 'Nobody') AS OccupantName
FROM Rooms
WHERE Rooms IN ('Room 1', 'Room 2', 'Room 3', 'Room 4')
```

For `MYSQL` you can use `IFNULL` in the same manner

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 8.0 where introduced [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/) you can use next approach:

- generate table from JSON rooms list and use LEFT JOIN with your table

```
SELECT 
    all_rooms.room Room, 
    COALESCE(rooms.name, 'NoBody') OccupiedBy
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    '["Room 1","Room 2","Room 3","Room 4"]',
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (room VARCHAR(64) PATH '$[0]')
) all_rooms
LEFT JOIN rooms USING(room);
```

[SQL editor online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/b94e450829826425d207155db2466ac1/)

Result:

```
+========+============+
| Room   | OccupiedBy |
+========+============+
| Room 1 | Person A   |
+--------+------------+
| Room 2 | NoBody     |
+--------+------------+
| Room 3 | NoBody     |
+--------+------------+
| Room 4 | Person B   |
+--------+------------+
```