# How to get back NULLs for elements that did not match using IN clause in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

```
SELECT 
  ColAlphaNum, 
  ColId 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE ColAlphaNum IN ('01AAA','02BBB','03CCC','04DDD')
```

The table contains records for values 01AAA, 02BBB. The sql returns the following result set (I need to query the data from "SomeTable" table only

```
 ColAlphaNum | ColId
 ------------+------
 01AAA       | 5
 02BBB       | 3
```

I want to return the non matching records values as NULL's as shown below but could not get it to work.

**Expected Output:**

```
ColAlphaNum | total
------------+------
01AAA       | 5
02BBB       | 3
03CCC       | NULL
04DDD       | NULL
```

I tried to achieve the same with case statements but could not get it to work. Tried this suggested solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41627508/2843342) it works but since I have to create a comma separated list of ColAlphaNum values from a json list and use them in the select statement above, the union all option may be cumbersome. Is there a way to achieve this in other ways.

Thank for your help.

Comment: You could build those values for your in statement to a table variable, and do a LEFT join on that table variable.  This way you would get all the ones that match and the ones that dont match (instead of the IN Statement)

Comment: Try Left-Joining your result to the original table?

Comment: The answer you liked to is the correct approach. If you can build a string such as `('x', 'y')` then you can also build a string such as `'x' UNION ALL 'y'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a table from the list using `UNION ALL` and `LEFT JOIN` with it (should work in SQL 2000):

```
SELECT List.ListItem, SomeTable.ColId
FROM (
    SELECT '01AAA' UNION
    SELECT '02BBB' UNION
    SELECT '03CCC' UNION
    SELECT '04DDD'
) AS List(ListItem)
LEFT JOIN SomeTable ON List.ListItem = SomeTable.ColAlphaNum
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of items in the `IN (...)` clause, a potentially better, more efficient method, might be to create a temporary table to hold the matches.

This sample code will not run on SQL Server 2000, since it relies on sample data that is created using functionality not available in SQL Server 2000.  Having said that, you don't need to create sample data on your real system, so that should not be a problem.  Also, WHY SQL SERVER 2000????  That is nearly 20 year-old code, and fully unsupported by Microsoft.  One shudders to think of the security implications.

Create the temp table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb...#Matches', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Matches;
CREATE TABLE #Matches
(
    AlphaNum char(5) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT Matches_pk
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
);
```

Insert 100 rows of test data into it (this won't run on SQL Server 2000):

```
INSERT INTO #Matches (AlphaNum)
SELECT TOP(100) 
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2)
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1  ), 2)
    + CHAR((CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) & 25) + 65)
    + CHAR((CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) & 25) + 65)
    + CHAR((CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) & 25) + 65)
FROM sys.syscolumns c1;
```

The contents of 10 rows from the temp table:

```
SELECT TOP(10) *
FROM #Matches;
```

```
╔══════════╗
║ AlphaNum ║
╠══════════╣
║ 00BQY    ║
║ 01RZJ    ║
║ 02YQB    ║
║ 03JAY    ║
║ 04QJB    ║
║ 05QIB    ║
║ 06ZYY    ║
║ 07QBJ    ║
║ 08ZAI    ║
║ 09QBA    ║
╚══════════╝
```

Create the `SomeTable` from your question, and fill it with 10,000 rows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SomeTable', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable
(
    SomeTableID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT SomeTable_pk
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , AlphaNum char(5) NOT NULL
    , SomeCol varchar(500) NOT NULL
);
```

Insert some test data (again, this part won't run on SQL Server 2000):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (AlphaNum, SomeCol)
SELECT TOP(10000) 
    AlphaNum = RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2)
               , (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) % 99)
               , 2)
        + CHAR((CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) & 25) + 65)
        + CHAR((CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) & 25) + 65)
        + CHAR((CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) & 25) + 65)
    , SomeCol = CONVERT(varchar(1000), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(500))
FROM sys.syscolumns c1
    CROSS JOIN sys.syscolumns c2;
```

Create a supporting non-clustered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SomeTable_AlphaNum
ON dbo.SomeTable (AlphaNum)
INCLUDE (SomeCol); --INCLUDE clause does not work on SQL Server 2000, ignore it.
```

Display all the rows from the temp table, with matches from `SomeTable` and `NULL` values for rows in the temp table that don't have a match in `SomeTable` (this DEFINITELY works on SQL Server 2000!):

```
SELECT m.AlphaNum
    , st.SomeCol
FROM #Matches m
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SomeTable st ON m.AlphaNum = st.AlphaNum;
```

First 20 rows from that output:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ AlphaNum ║       SomeCol        ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 00BQY    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 01RZJ    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 02YQB    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 03JAY    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 04QJB    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 05QIB    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 06ZYY    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 07QBJ    ║ SR{m‘x ™¨Hó‹µäôÅPÓ   ║
║ 08ZAI    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 09QBA    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 10RQA    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 11IAZ    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 12RZI    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 13ZRA    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 14IAI    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 15BIZ    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 16JBI    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 17AYJ    ║ Å N©U…C4Mòº³5ö„iÅ    ║
║ 18ZJI    ║ NULL                 ║
║ 19YRI    ║ NULL                 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` construct & do the `left join` :

```
select t.ColAlphaNum, s.ColId as total
from ( values ('01AAA'),('02BBB'),('03CCC'),('04DDD') 
     ) t(ColAlphaNum) left join
     SomeTable s
     on s.ColAlphaNum = t.ColAlphaNum;
```

Comment: This is tagged sql-server-2000 and I don't think the `VALUES()` constructor was available until 2008.

Comment: @Yogesh sorry, like Taryn mentioned I updated my question with tag sql-server-2000 and the mentioned query won't work for me. Thank you though.

Comment: @Taryn. . . When i answered, it has tagged only `SQL`, `SQL-Server`.